# SQL Server to rds sql. do we need to change connection string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

We have simple 3 tier .NET application with SQL Server 2012. It is 700GB
Planing to move RDS SQL server.

Any limitation or new findings while moving to RDS SQL Server which you may come across?

Do we need to change any application code or SQL objects like stored procedures, functions, triggers?

Does AWS DMS import all data & objects from SQL Server to RDS SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You should need to change anything in your application apart from the connection details (i.e. host name, user, password) to match the RDS configuration.